# How to return value from nested function in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, iife

I want to return value from nested function in javascript.

**this is my code:**

```
export const getArtistMusics = (id) => {
    return cheerioInit(`https://mrtehran.com/artist/${id}`).then(($) => {
        const SECTION = $('.musicbox-tracks .musicbox-item')
        let musics = []

        SECTION.each((i, elem) => {
            return (async () => {
                const PAGE_LINK = $(elem).attr('mtp-data-url')
                return await getMusic(PAGE_LINK)
            })()
        })

        return musics
    })
}
```

as you see I returned an async IIFE function, but I don't know how to return the value (promise)  outside of `SECTION.each` block.

I want to push values to musics array and then return it.

What is the solution for this situation?

Comment: `each`/`forEach` and promises rarely work well together - try using a for loop inside an async function - or `.map` and Promise.all are also a good combination

Comment: replace the code after `const SECTION = ....` with `return Promise.all(Array.from(SECTION, elem => getMusic($(elem).attr('mtp-data-url'))));`

Comment: You're returning a promise on line 2. You'll need to `await` that stuff if you want to return a value.

Comment: Any value returned from a function called by [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is discarded. The `SECTION.each` function needs to push promises into `music` and then, after the each loop finishes, `await Promise.all(music)`;

Comment: @JaromandaX
@JayB
@traktor53

```each``` is built in function for cheerio.js library

Comment: yes, @ShaSha - and it still isn't *compatible* with Promises - did you even try my code suggestion?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks it works